# SQL Server Logic for Detecting Gaps in Dates Sequence

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, while-loop, sequence, common-table-expression

I have the following table :

```
     Plan     Start Date     End Date     Order    
    ------------------------------------------
      1    1st Jan, 2014  31st Jan, 2014   1
      1    1st Feb, 2014  24th Feb, 2014   2
      1   25th Feb, 2014  30th Jun, 2014   3
      1    7th Jul, 2014  28th Aug, 2014   4
      1    1st Sep, 2014  30th Sep, 2014   5
      1    1st Oct, 2014  31st Dec, 2014   6
```

As is evident from the above data, for plan 1, orders 1,2,3 are continuous, then we have a gap, then order 4, then again a gap and then orders 5,6 are continuous. For the plan 1, I want to bundle the coverages as follows : (1,2,3) ,(4),(5,6) and the expected result set should be as follows :

```
     Plan     Start Date     End Date         
    -------------------------------------
      1    1st Jan, 2014  30th Jun, 2014 
      1    7th Jul, 2014  28th Aug, 2014 
      1    1st Sep, 2014  31st Dec, 2014
```

I used a basic while loop iterative logic to achieve my desired output. However, when there is a large number of records (say 1 million), the performance of the while loop logic is taking a major hit (as it is a row-wise operation). I tried coming up with a recursive-CTE-based approach, but could not get the desired result. Any input where a batch-wise logic can be used will be really helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Subquery in `WHERE` filter out continous rows. Subquery in `SELECT` will find the date range end.

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab([Plan] INT, StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE, [Order] INT )

INSERT INTO #tab VALUES
(1, '2014-01-01', '2014-01-31', 1),(1, '2014-02-01', '2014-02-24', 2),
(1, '2014-02-25', '2014-06-30', 3),(1, '2014-07-07', '2014-08-28', 4),
(1, '2014-09-01', '2014-09-30', 5),(1, '2014-10-01', '2014-12-31', 6);
```

Query:

```
SELECT [Plan],D.StartDate, 
   [EndDate] = (SELECT MIN(E.EndDate)
                FROM #tab E
                WHERE E.EndDate >= D.EndDate
                 AND E.[Plan] = D.[Plan]
                 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                 FROM #tab E2
                                 WHERE DATEADD(d,1,E.StartDate) < E2.StartDate
                                   AND DATEADD(d,1,E.EndDate) >= E2.StartDate
                                   AND E.[Plan] = E2.[Plan]))
FROM #tab D
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM #tab D2
                  WHERE D.StartDate <= DATEADD(d, 1,D2.EndDate)
                    AND D.EndDate > D2.EndDate
                    AND D.[Plan] = D2.[Plan])
ORDER BY [Plan], StartDate;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/381550)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ Plan ║      StartDate      ║       EndDate       ║
╠══════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║    1 ║ 2014-01-01 00:00:00 ║ 2014-06-30 00:00:00 ║
║    1 ║ 2014-07-07 00:00:00 ║ 2014-08-28 00:00:00 ║
║    1 ║ 2014-09-01 00:00:00 ║ 2014-12-31 00:00:00 ║
╚══════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

see another query

```
    declare @tab table ([Plan] INT, StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE, [Order] INT )      
    INSERT INTO @tab VALUES
    (1, '2014-01-01', '2014-01-31', 1),(1, '2014-02-01', '2014-02-24', 2),
    (1, '2014-02-25', '2014-06-30', 3),(1, '2014-07-07', '2014-08-28', 4),
    (1, '2014-09-01', '2014-09-30', 5),(1, '2014-10-01', '2014-12-31', 6)

    select [plan], Max(case when ro in (1,4,5) then startDate end) st,
    Max(case when ro in (3,4,0) then endDate end) et from (
    select *, ([order]-1) / 6 as grp,
    [order]%6 as ro, case when ([order] % 6)<4 and ([order] % 6)!=0 then 1
 when ([order] % 6)=4 then 2 else 3 end as subgrp
    from @tab) t group by [plan],grp,subgrp
```